# Why does julia express this expression in this complex way?

Tags: julia

I followed the documentation of julia:

```
julia> :(a in (1,2,3))
:($(Expr(:in, :a, :((1,2,3)))))
```

Now that `:(a in (1,2,3))==:($(Expr(:in, :a, :((1,2,3)))))`, why does julia express this expression in this way？ And what does `$` exactly means? It seems to me that `$` just evaluates the next expression in a global scope. I found the documentation unclear about this.

Comment: Please refer to the Julia language **Metaprogramming** documentation: http://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/metaprogramming

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason `:(a in (1,2,3))` is displayed awkwardly as `:($(Expr(...)))` is because the `show` function for Expr typed objects (`show_unquoted` in `show.jl`) does not understand the `in` infix operator and fallbacks into a generic printing format.

Essentially it is the same as `:(1 + 1)` except that `show_unquoted` recognizes `+` as an infix operator and formats it nicely.

In any case, `:(...)` and `$(...)` are inverse operators in some sense, so `:($(..thing..))` is exactly like `..thing..`, which in this case is `Expr(:in,:a,:((1,2,3)))`.

One can see this weirdness in `:(1+1)` for example. The output is of Expr type, as `typeof(:(1+1))==Expr` confirms. It is actually `Expr(:+,1,1)`, but typing `Expr(:+,1,1)` on the REPL will show `:($(Expr(:+,1,1)))` - the generic formatting style of Expr typed objects.

Fixing `show.jl` to handle `in` could be a nice change. But the issue is harmless and concerns display formatting.

Comment: Notice that at least since julia `v"0.5.0-dev+1020"`, `:(a in (1, 2, 3))` shows exactly `:(a in (1,2,3))`, as @Chong Wang expected.
`

Answer (score 5):

`$` is the interpolation command, Julia use this notation to interpolate Strings as well as Expression:

```
julia> a=1;
julia> "test $a" # => "test 1"
julia> :(b+$a) # => :(b + 1)
```

When you type a command in Julia REPL, it tries to evaluates the command and  if the code do not have `;` char at the end it prints the result, so it's more related to printing functions, that what will be seen on REPL, when a command executes.
so if you want to see the real contents of a variable one possibility is to use `dump` function:

```
julia> dump(:(a+b))
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array(Any,(3,))
    1: Symbol +
    2: Symbol a
    3: Symbol b
  typ: Any

julia> dump(:(a in b))
Expr
  head: Symbol in
  args: Array(Any,(2,))
    1: Symbol a
    2: Symbol b
  typ: Any
```

It's clear from above tests, that both expressions use a common data structure of `Expr` with `head`, `args` and `typ` **without any `$` inside**.
Now try to evaluate and print result:

```
julia> :(a in b)
:($(Expr(:in, :a, :b)))

julia> :(a+b)
:(a + b)
```

We already know that both command create a same structure but REPL can't show the result of `:(a in b)` better that an `Expr` of result of another `Expr` and it's why there in a `$` inside. But when dealing with `:(a+b)`, REPL do more intelligently and understands that this:

```
Expr
  head: Symbol call
  args: Array(Any,(3,))
    1: Symbol +
    2: Symbol a
    3: Symbol b
  typ: Any
```

is equal to `:(a+b)`.